# java while (LinkedList.iterator().hasNext()) does not work

Tags: java, iterator, while-loop

I have the following while loop, if I put this.boatTripsList.iterator().hasNext() in the while loop condition, it throws error. When I create iterator then put in the while loop condition, it will work then. Why is this? Thanks & Regards. (the second version throws error)

```
 public Journey(List<BoatTrip> trips) {
   this.boatTripsList = new LinkedList<BoatTrip>();
   Iterator<BoatTrip> iterator = trips.iterator();
   //add the given boat trips to the boattrips list
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         BoatTrip thistrip = iterator.next();
         this.boatTripsList.add(thistrip);
    }
}



public Journey(List<BoatTrip> trips) {
   this.boatTripsList = new LinkedList<BoatTrip>();
   //add the given boat trips to the boattrips list
    while (trips.iterator().hasNext()) {
         BoatTrip thistrip = iterator.next();
         this.boatTripsList.add(thistrip);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh wait, your edited code has nothing to do with the initial code. What gives?

Comment: Certainly it works. It just doesn't do what you want. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is normal: if your while condition is `while(trips.iterator().hasNext())`, you create *a new iterator each time*. If your list is not empty, the condition will therefore always be true...

While in the loop itself, you use the iterator you created before entering the loop... As a result, you'll get a `NoSuchElementException` when this iterator is empty.

Use:

```
final Iterator<Whatever> = list.iterator();
Whatever whatever;

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     whatever = iterator.next();
     // do whatever stuff
}
```

But for walking lists, a foreach loop is preferred:

```
for (final BoatTrip trip: tripList)
    // do whatever is needed
```

And if you want to add the contents of a list to another, use `.addAll()`:

```
// no need for the "this" qualifier, there is no name conflict
boatTripList.addAll(trips);
```

Comment: Thanks, so you are saying for code while (trips.iterator().hasNext()), i create a new iterator each time ?

Comment: @Jeffrey yes, exactly. Don't do that ;)

Comment: @Jeffrey also, if it's to make a copy, just use a copy constructor as I mentioned; no need to iterate yourself

Comment: @Jeffrey no problem ;) You should have a good look at the javadoc for `List`, there is plenty of stuff in it

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the `iterator` you requested on the first line of your code there - you're requesting a new one each time, so it will always have a next.

Comment: I put the code like that to show the two versions of my program. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A call to .iterator() obtains a new iterator. If you do that in the loop, you will always obtain a new iterator rather than iterating over an existing iterator.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why the second version failed.

Answer (score 0):

this.boatTripsList.iterator().hasNext() is wrong

this.boatTripsList.hasNext() is correct